# Replace Sprite in cocos2d with Animation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have created two bounding boxes in cocos2d for iPhone and when they intersect the image from selSprite replaces the image in targetSprite if their tags match. I want to give a nice animation when the bounding boxes collide. The following code replaces the sprites successfully but the FadeOut animation runs **AFTER** the images have been replaced. The animation should run when the images are being replaced. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(getSpriteRect, selSpriteRect)) {

        if ([selSprite tag] == ([targetSprite tag]-7)) {
            //NSLog(@"%d", [targetSprite tag]);
            //NSLog(@"%@", [selectedSpritesToBeUsedLater objectAtIndex:[selSprite tag]]);

            CCSprite *replacedImage = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:[targetSprite tag]];

            CCSprite *spriteToBeUsedInTex = [selectedSpritesToBeUsedLater objectAtIndex:[selSprite tag]];

            id removeSpriteAction = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:2.0f];

            id removeSelSprite = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeSelSpriteByTag)];

            CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:removeSpriteAction, removeSelSprite, nil];

            [selSprite runAction:sequence]; 

            CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"color-0%d.png", [spriteToBeUsedInTex tag]+1]];

            [replacedImage setTexture:tex];

        }
    }
} }

-(void)removeSelSpriteByTag {
[self removeChildByTag:[selSprite tag] cleanup:YES]; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CCSpawn` instead of `CCSequence` then.

Comment: I does not work. Can you guide me on how to do it? I replaced CCSequence with CCSpawn. Now there is no effect, it just snaps into place!